# Sequel Pro - import .sq3 db

Tags: database, sequelpro

Using MAC, when I Import a database formatted as sq3 I've this error:

> An error occurred when reading the file, as it could not be read in the encoding you selected (Autodetect - Thai (Windows, DOS)).
>
> Only 0 queries were executed.

How do I import it to see working properly?

Regards

EDIT: The encoding is set to Autodetect

Answer (score 1):

You need to select "Western (Mac OS Roman)" as the encoding format for the file.